# How can I deserialize JSON into this POCO class?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

ERROR:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserItem' to 'RootObject'**

How can I deserialize JSON into this POCO class?

I'm simply trying to deserilize json data into C# custom poco class as shown below and here is what i have done so far;

```
public static UserItem DownloadJSONString(string urlJson)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = wc.DownloadString(urlJson);
        UserItem userItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        return userItems;
    }            
}
```

I'm kind of stuck here

**here my Json:**

```
{
    "meta":
    {
        "status":200,
        "resultSet":
        {
            "id":"05"
        },
        "pagination":
        {
            "count":2,
            "pageNum":1,
            "pageSize":2
        }
    },
    "results":   
    {
        "id":0,
        "name":
        "title",
        "items":
        [
            {
                "id":0,
                "name":"English",
                "title":"English",
            },
            {
                "id":0,
                "name":"Spanish",
                "title":"Spanish;",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**here is my json object (generate from json to c# class)**

```
public class ResultSet
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int pageNum { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public ResultSet resultSet { get; set; }
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my simple `UserItem` POCO class**

```
public class UserItem 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong? Are you getting errors?

Comment: error: i know that what i am doing is incorrect but not sure how to convert the `RootObject` to `UserItem` which is C# class --- error = Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserItem' to 'RootObject'

Comment: Naturally. `UserItem` is *not related* to `RootObject` and thus the [deserialized] object *cannot* be assigned to such a variable - which is why the compiler type error results. Consider: `RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json); UserItem userItem = DoWhateverYouNeedToGetOneOfThese(root);` It should be fairly trivial to create the missing method as appropriate in this case.

Comment: @user2864740: i am not sure what you talking... do you see my return data type is UserItem and i dont have that in my json object.

Comment: I am aware of that. `DoWhateverYouNeedToGetOneOfThese(root)`. Using the `new` keyword is allowed.

Comment: i understand but can you please show me the code you think will works?

Comment: @AbuHamzah No. Because *you* should be able to do that given an object of type `RootObject`. The JSON is irrelevant. It's all about accessing C# properties and collections.

Comment: sorry but doesn't  make any sense... anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var userItem = root.results.items
                           .Select(i => new UserItem
                           {
                               id = i.id,
                               name = i.name,
                               title = i.title
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

return userItem;
```

As you already know, you can't just convert the `Item` class into a `UserItem`, but you can build one. One thing to note here is that obviously if you only want to return one you'll have to just grab one. Here I've grabbed the first or default. The default would be `null` if the list were empty for example.

Comment: my json returning me around 5k and it took good 20to30 seconds is that normal when doing deserializeObject?

Comment: @AbuHamzah, it returned 5K "items"?

Comment: @AbuHamzah, then I would expect that to take a while, yes. Now, that was on your development machine I'm guessing; and in `Debug`; so I would expect it to perform better in PROD. **But,** you might want to find a way to minimize that result set *if you can.*

Comment: @AbuHamzah, what do you mean query child object?

Comment: what i mean by that within `Results` i have another `List<Topic>` how would i do within the `.Select(i => new UserItem` i try to use `.SelectMany...` does not work....

Comment: @AbuHamzah, that's another whole question. How about you grab the code you've got already and start a new question for that one; there are many here who can help you with that.

Comment: here is the question i have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111431/deserialize-json-into-poco-class-with-nested-select