# Deserialize JSON into POCO class with Nested Select

Tags: c#, json

my question is continuation of what i have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110468/how-can-i-deserialize-json-into-this-poco-class/20110518#comment29967790_20110518)

I'm simply trying to deserilize json data into C# custom poco class as shown below and here is what i have done so far;

```
public static UserItem DownloadJSONString(string urlJson)
{
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var userItem = root.results
                       .Select(i => new UserItem
                       {
                           id = i.id,
                           name = i.name,
                           title = i.title,

                           //tried using `Any` but does not seems work...
                           audience = (from _tag in root.results.SelectMany(x => x.tags) //<<<
                                       select new Audience { id = _tag.Id .....}).ToList()

                       }).ToList();

      return userItem;          
}
```

**here is my json object (generate from json to c# class)**

```
public class Tags
{
   public List<object> audience { get; set; }
}    

public class Results
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Tags tags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my simple `UserItem` POCO class**

```
public class UserItem 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Audience audience { get; set; }
}

public class Audience 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `audience` property isn't strongly typed? It's just a `List<object>`. How are you going to convert that into an `Audience` type?

Comment: i am not sure, i use http://json2csharp.com/# thats what it gives me as `Object`

Comment: Okay, what does the JSON look like for the `tags`?

Comment: {
  "id": 9,
  "name": "School"   
} object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
{
  "id": 22,
  "name": "College"
} object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like all of the others, build a class for it and it will be deserialized into it:

```
public class TagAudience
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and then instead of `List<object>` in the `Tags` class, use `List<TagAudience>`. Finally, when you want to get to those:

```
audience = i.Tags.audience
    .Select(ta => new Audience
    {
        id = ta.id,
        name = ta.name
    }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: instead of `i.Tags.audience` i was doing `root.results.Tags.audience
` - thanks for your help.

Comment: @AbuHamzah, I'm glad I could be of assistance!